# How do you parse a string using Blaze Spacebars

Tags: templates, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

Most of the documentation for Blaze Template engine focuses on using DOM nodes. I would like to process a string using Spacebars and get the finished string back.

My goal is something simple like this:

```
var str = Spacebars(data, inputString);
```

I don't want to do anything with the DOM. I found a function that [converts a string to a Blaze template](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-template-from-string/blob/master/Template.fromString.js) but I would like to get a string back not a template object. My own first try was something like this:

```
var str = Blaze.toHTML(Blaze.With(data, function() { return $(inputString); }))
```

The [documentation mentions Blaze.toHTML()](http://blazejs.org/api/blaze.html#Blaze-toHTML) can return a string.

Comment: What happened with your first try? Also have you looked at ssr?